# Is there a way to apply/bake a mask or clip to an svg, leaving you with one path?

Tags: svg, inkscape

I have a set of svgs I need to minify and I noticed that many of them have two paths when they could just use one path. They use one path for the shape and one for the color.

I can manually unset the mask and then do an intersect operation on each but this is very time consuming and not scalable.

This file is an example of the kind of clip I'm talking about:
https://svgur.com/s/Eac

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 284 284" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:1.41421;"><clipPath id="_clip1"><circle cx="140.476" cy="140.476" r="42.52"/></clipPath><g clip-path="url(#_clip1)"><rect x="57.702" y="57.702" width="165.548" height="165.548" style="fill:#ff91a5;"/></g></svg>
```

Comment: Please post a code example in-line or this question will probably be closed - your code hosting site is over quota and the SVG can't be viewed.